# Python 3.8.5 alternative to .replace with csv.reader and UTF-8 mystery encodings

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I have spent 5 hours throughout the dark recesses of SO so I am posting this question as a last resort, and I am genuinely hoping someone can point me in the right direction here:

Scenario:

- I have some .csv files (UTF-8 CSVs: verified with the file -I command) from Google surveys that are in multiple languages. Output:

  `download.csv: application/csv; charset=utf-8`
- I have a "dictionary" file that has the translations for the questions and answers (one column is the $language and the other is English).
- There are LOTS of special type characters (umlauts and French accent letters, etc..) in the data from Google, because French, German, Dutch
- The dictionary file I built reads fine as UTF-8 including special characters and creates the find/replace keys accurately (verified with print commands)

The issue is that the Google files only read correctly (maintain proper characters) using the csv.read function in Python. However, that function does not have a .replace and so I can do one or the other:

- read in the source file, make no replacements, and get a perfect copy (not what I need)
- convert the csv files/rows to a fileinput/string (UTF-8 still, mind) and get an utterly thrashed output file with missing replacements because the data "looses" the encoding between the csv read and the string somehow?

The code (here) comes closest to working, except there is no .replace method on csv.reader:

```
import csv  

#set source, output
source = 'fr_to_trans.csv'
output = 'fr_translated.csv'
dictionary = 'frtrans.csv'
find = []
replace = []

# build the dictionary itself:
with open(dictionary, encoding='utf-8') as dict_file:
    for line in dict_file:
        #print(line)
        temp_split = []
        temp_split = line.split(',')
        if "!!" in temp_split[0] :
            temp_split[0] = temp_split[0].replace("!!", ",")
        find.append(temp_split[0])
        if "!!" in temp_split[1] :
            temp_split[1] = temp_split[1].replace("!!", ",")
        replace.append(temp_split [1])
        #print(len(find))
        #print(len(replace))

#set loop counters
check_each = len(find)
# Read in the file to parse
with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as s_file, open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as t_file :
    output_writer = csv.writer(t_file)
    for row in csv.reader(s_file):
        the_row = row
        print(the_row) #THIS RETURNS THE CORRECT, FORMATTED, UTF-8 DATA
        i = 0
        # find and replace everything in the find array with it's value in the replace array
        while i < check_each :  
            print(find[i])
            print(replace[i])
            # THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK:
            the_row = the_row.replace(find[i], replace[i])
            i = i + 1
        output_writer.writerow(the_row)
```

I have to assume that even though the Google files *say* they are UTF-8, they are a special "Google branded UTF-8" or some such nonsense. The fact that the file opens correctly with csv.reader, but then you can do nothing to it is infuriating beyond measure.

Just to clarify what I have tried:

- Treat files as text and let Python sort out the encoding (fails)
- Treat files as UTF-8 text (fails)
- Open file as UTF-8, replace strings, and write out using the csv.writer (fails)
- Convert the_row to a string, then replace, then write out with csv.writer (fails)
- Quick edit - tried utf-8-sig with strings - better, but the output is still totally mangled because it isn't reading it as a csv, but strings

I have not tried:

- "cell by cell" comparison instead of the whole row (working on that while this percolates on SO)
- Different encoding of the file (I can only get UTF-8 CSVs so would need some sort of utility?)

If these were ASCII text I would have been done ages ago, but this whole "UTF-8 that isn't but is" thing is driving me mad. Anyone got any ideas on this?

Comment: There's no such thing as "special Google branded UTF-8", you'll have to be more specific than that.

Comment: *"Treat files as text and let Python sort out the encoding (fails)"* there is no such thing as "magic text file encoding detection" either. Python cannot sort this out for you. Either the encoding is clearly declared, be it through HTTP headers, or through a byte order mark, or you need to *know* it before opening the text file.

Comment: You might want to add relevant samples of your files that a) show the file structure, and b) reproducibly demonstrate the issue. Overall, it's not as hard as it appears to be in your question, but you have a few concepts mixed up.

Comment: I wish that I could but they contain a lot of PII/brand information/proprietary info and I cannot share the source data files.     I think the biggest issue is that unlike most find/replace exercises, I want to replace entire cells of a sheet effectively, by matching a full phrase in French for example, and then replacing every occurrence of it with the English translation. The issue arrises when the file encoding for special characters is not preserved, and the matching fails/the output is corrupted with special characters. Why reading a file as UTF-8 vs a native CSV is different is the crux.

Comment: Post fake data in the same format.  We don't need many lines.

Answer (score 1):

Each row yielded by `csv.reader` is a *list* of cell values like

```
['42', 'spam', 'eggs']
```

Thus the line

```
# THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK:
the_row = the_row.replace(find[i], replace[i])
```

cannot possibly work, because lists don't have a replace method.

What might work is to iterate over the row list and find/replace on each cell value (I'm assuming they are all strings)

```
the_row = [cell.replace(find[i], replace[i]) for cell in the row]
```

However, if all you want to do is replace all instances of some characters in the file with some other characters then it's simpler to open the file as a text file and replace without invoking any csv machinery:

```py
with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as s_file, open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as t_file :
    text = source.read()
    for old, new in zip(find, replace):
        text = text.replace(old, new)
    t_file.write(text)
```

If the find/replace mapping is the same for all files, you can use [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to avoid the for loop.

```py
# Make a reusable translation table
trans_table = str.maketrans(dict(zip(find, replace)))

with open(source, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as s_file, open(output, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as t_file :
    text = source.read()
    text = text.translate(trans_table)
    t_file.write(text)
```

For clarity: csvs are text files, only formatted so that their contents can be interpreted as rows and columns.  If you want to manipulate their contents as pure text it's fine to edit them as normal text files: as long as you don't change any of the characters used as delimiters or quote marks they will still be usuable as csvs when you want to use them as such.

Comment: I was hoping you would chime in, your answer on another post led me to utf-sig as well.

I tried the cell.replace and it kinda works, but puts every letter of the translated value into its own column.

The trans_table method fails on the values in find and replace because I do not understand how to use it yet (still researching), but could be it.

The issue is I am matching entire phrases in other languages that  have to match the complete phrase to replace the complete phrase. They are not in the same field every time, or in the same order always.